# Euclid Elements: Original Greek version?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Does anyone know where this is located?

I have the Heiberg version, but I think it was translated to Greek from Arabic or perhaps intermediate Latin. Some stack exchange members have claimed it exists.

Thanks

Comment: The [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) may be a better place for this question.

Comment: Heidelberg? Do you mean Heiberg?

Comment: Are you still here, Nick?

Comment: Never mind, Nick, I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that there is a misunderstanding in that Heiberg did not *translate* Euclid into Greek, instead he *transcribed* ancient Greek editions of Euclid. See for example [this page about Heiberg](http://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/geometry-history/heiberg-heath.htm) and [this wikipedia page about Heiberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_Ludvig_Heiberg_(historian)).

[Here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Euclid/Euclid.html) is a link to Fitzpatrick's edition which shows the Heiberg Greek edition side-by-side with Fitzpatrick's English translation.